# Simulate :focus state on a div when key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want previous and next navigation using left and right arrow keys.  I want the state of the links to change to :focus upon pressing of the arrow keys as well for tactile feedback.  Perhaps addClass could work too, but I can't figure it out.

Code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wBWTx/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#element").focus()` should do the trick just fine. That doesn't simulate focus - that actually change focus, which is what you want from a usability perspective anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 46) { 
       $('.next a').focus('test');
       return false;
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

The addClass approach would be your best bet.  There are a few issues in the fiddle you posted however:

```
if (e.keyCode == 44)
```

is missing an opening brace and causing a compile error. This should be:

```
if (e.keyCode == 44) {
```

Also are keycodes 44 (PrintScreen) and 46(Delete) what you were looking for here?

Making these small changes appears to make your fiddle work as intended.